# Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Daniil-Myasnikovs-MacBook-Pro.lower-test

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql

My environment:

Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.8
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

I was using this version until I tried to install MAMP on top of that. After that I have stoped MySQL server, and now I can't start it again. In terminal it writes me back:

```
  110825 17:09:04 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Daniil-Myasnikovs-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
  110825 17:09:04 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Daniil-Myasnikovs-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
  mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
  110825 17:09:04 [ERROR] Aborting

  110825 17:09:04 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

If you can give me a hand with this, that would be more than helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that the directory **/var/lib/mysql** does actually exist and corresponds to your data directory?
If it does not, then you probably must specify otherwise the datadir parameter under the mysqld section

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: You must find your my.cnf configuration file and edit it. I am not really sure where this file is placed on a Mac.

Comment: I found solution, sounds like I'm a Windows user, but that's work. What I do is just restart my Mac :)